# How to get URL of a resource in visual studio c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am making a simplePlayer WindowsForm. In order for the video to play i need to provide the url

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"C:\Users\Stephan\Desktop\trasa-1250.wmv";
```

Now i need to either use relative paths or add them as a resource and get the url for that resource but i don't know how to do that:

```
wplayer.URL = Resources.trasa_1250.
```

I've tried using

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"~\trasa-1250.wmv";
```

and

```
 axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @".\trasa-1250.wmv";
```

but printing @"~\trasa-1250.wmv";  and @.\trasa-1250.wmv"; prints them as they are without replacing the ~ or the .

Comment: why cant you give the absolute path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the absolute path for a file, by supplying a name relative to the *current directory*, you can use:

```
string filename = "trasa-1250.wmv";
string path = Path.GetFullPath(filename);
```

For completeness sake, to create an actual Url from this:

```
string url = new Uri(path).AbsoluteUri;
```

You can't create a Url to an embedded resource, unless you program the player to accept a custom Url scheme (to allow, for instance, "resource://assemblyName.namespace.resourceName") and process it correctly.

A common alternative is to let the caller provide the `Stream` from which to read the media - and let them decide on how to access the resource.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial that will help:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nF-HYoTurc8

You could also get the URL like this:

```
   Uri MyUri = new Uri(@"/Resources/trasa-1250.wmv", UriKind.Relative);
```